# Android build fails when using activity-alias

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

After I added a activity-alias, the build fails with:

```
error: attribute 'android:name' in <activity-alias> tag must be a valid Java class name.
```

Even if the Android Developers documentation says, the name doesn't have refer to an actual class.

> android:name
>
> A unique name for the alias. The name should resemble a fully qualified class name. But, unlike the name of the target activity, the alias name is arbitrary; it does not refer to an actual class.

Here's my activity declaration:

```
...

<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

<activity-alias
    android:name="MainActivity-2"
    android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>

...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its clear here that we can choose any unique name for the alias but what's not clear is that the unique name should be a valid class name (i.e. name should not contain "-", space, special character, etc.).

Thats why you are getting your error(`error: attribute 'android:name' in <activity-alias> tag must be a valid Java class name.`) while building your application.

Comment: Thank you! The hyphens was the problem. Now, the build runs without errors.